# Как показать только часть бэкграунда?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть див#1 у него задан бэкграунд и размер (к примеру 100%).
Есть див#2 у него background: inherit а размер 100px на 100px. Задача состоит в том, чтобы див#2 отображал туже часть бэкграунда что и закрывает собой находясь в диве#1.

Comment: если прям бэкраундом то без js никак, но почему не сделать этому перекрывающему div пустой background ?

Comment: Согласен с @eicto. Но также можно воспользоваться свойством background-position

Comment: может стоит поиграть со свойством opacity

Comment: @artem328, а оно работает с calc ? тогда мб да.

Answer (score 1):

```
див#2 {
```

background: transparent;
}